# Is it possible to leave the Revolt against Roman Holy Empire?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I started as Duke of Savoy and join the faction to get independence. The War is just dragging and we are mostly loosing (-80%+ warscore) but it keeps dragging. I am not the liege of the revolt. I cannot attack anybody except to support the useless battles from the Revolt army.

Is there really nothing I can do except waiting? My intrigue is far too low to assassinate the liege.

Is there a way to quit the revolt?
Is it possible to influence the revolt in any ways after it is started?

Thank you! :)

-- SMALL UPDATE --

After many years, we finally lost (reached -100%) and we all got imprisoned (those who supported the independence faction). I would still like to know if there was any other possibilities... because as far as I get it now, it is quite useless to join the revolt unless you are the liege. I think the AI is not good enough to manage the war (we had 250%+ liege power before the revolt launch).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Once you are a part of a Revolt War you are committed. Your only way of influencing the revolt from there is by helping your revolt leader win the war. And yes, the AI isn't the best at winning faction-revolt wars.